# datepicker stops working when I apply the form-control class

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a textbox with a working jquery datepicker applied to it. if I add the `.form-control` class to the textbox and reload the page, the datepicker stopped working. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: How are you initialising the datepicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured it out myself. The datepicker object takes it's z-index from the item it is being attached to. It turns out that `.input-group .from-control` sets the z-index in a way that, in this case, was causing it to appear underneath that item's container instead of on top. I just increased the z-index of that item in order to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. I ended up using the [TopZIndex](https://code.google.com/archive/p/topzindex/) jQuery plugin.

Just download the plugin and load it into your page:

```
<script src='/path/to/jquery.topzindex.js'></script>
```

And include this simple script (written by yours truly) in your page:

```
$('.hasDatepicker').click(function() {
    $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', $.topZIndex() + 1);
});
```

Now the dates are ripe and ready to be picked.